# Error when converting a date and/or time from a character string

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

Getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I m trying to get a date value from user and save it in datetime datatype in SQL Server.

But getting this error. Please help.

Comment: You can tell by the colorization of the string that you're missing quotes around `onedate`

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) alert!

Comment: Works if I add quotes but if i select future dates gives the below error - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Y I read it but I need to add datetime values from date time picker in c#

Comment: Please read the duplicate link. It will work for you.